# Why is USB3 5Gbe network adapter half the speed as upload on ubuntu 20.04 server and limited to 800 Mbit/s download but 2Gbit/s upload on 5gig fiber?

Tags: networking, drivers, server, usb, raspberrypi

I have connected a QNAP QNA-UC5G1T 5Gbe usb network adapter to a raspberry pi running Ubuntu server 20.04.5 LTS. I also have a 5Gig fiber internet connection and a 10G switch and 10G router and get around 4Gbit/s speed both Download and Upload on Ubuntu desktop normally.

I had to enable this adapter as the eth1 interface by editing the file in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml like so by adding an eth1 entry

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
        eth1:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Then running

```
sudo netplan apply
```

It is only allowing under 1GB/s speed download, more like 750Mbits/s, but is reaching nearly 2GB/s upload on eth1. I am testing this with speedtest-cli for the speed estimates.

Further, when I run

```
ip a show eth1
```

It outputs a qlen of 1000, which it should be 5000

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/XX brd XXX.XXX.XX.XXX scope global dynamic eth1
       valid_lft 85855sec preferred_lft 85855sec
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And `ifconfig`

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet XXX.XXX.XX.XXX  netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.0  broadcast XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
        inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:11:22:33:44:55  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4195  bytes 992272 (992.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 47  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4107  bytes 595608 (595.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This shows a txqueuelen of 1000

But when I run

```
ethtool eth1
```

It outputs and clearly shows link modes of 5000baseT/Full, and Speed: 5000Mb/s

```
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
                            2500baseT/Full 
                            5000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
                            2500baseT/Full 
                            5000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 5000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

And when I run `sudo lshw -C network`

I get

```
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 55:44:33:22:11:00
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=v2.0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:2.1
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 00:11:22:33:44:55
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=aqc111 driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=3.1.6 ip=XXX.XXX.XX.XXX link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

My network:1, or eth1, clearly shows a limit of capacity of 1Gbit/s, and shows capabilities of max 1000bt-fd.

I have figured out how to update the qlen attribute of the `ip a show eth1` to be 5000, and the txqueuelen of `ifconfig eth1` by "Configuring the udev rule in the file "/lib/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules" to the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add|change", DRIVERS=="aqc111", ATTR{address}=="00:11:22:33:44:55", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1", ATTR{tx_queue_len}="5000"
```

The above instruction comes from the suse support docs found here: https://www.suse.com/zh-cn/support/kb/doc/?id=000019932

Now on reboot, both `ip a show eth1` and `ifconfig eth1` show the updated 5000 attribute. But the `sudo lshw -C network` command still shows the capactiy as 1Gbit/s and the highest capabilities is still 1000bt-fd.

Is there a way to update these values output by `lshw -C network`, so that the adapter can go above the 1Gbit/s amount on download? And why is upload going at around 2Gbit/s and not limited by the capacity of 1Gbit/s like downloads?

I should note that the drivers for this network adapter come included in Ubuntu server and Desktop. I have also tried installing the most recent drivers on the Marvell website and that does not change anything. They are the aqc111 drivers.

I have also been able to get this working on Ubuntu desktop as expected, without any special configuration, just plug and play. I ran the speedtest just now and got about 2.2Gbit/s download and nearly 3.5Gbit/s upload on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.5.

But for some reason am having a hard time figuring out if there is a way to increase the download speed on Ubuntu server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A limit and or a problem with the USB port?

Comment: @David The RPi port is USB3.0, and supposedly the theoretical transfer speed of USB 3.0 is 4.8 Gbit/s (600MBps). It is weird because download is around 800Mbit/s but upload reaches over 2Gbit/s. I am unable to figure out what is limiting download. And I have two different raspberry pi 4 model b's, both with Ubuntu server 20.04.5 installed, and 2 different USB3 5Gbit/s network adapters, and they both are performing the same, so I don't believe it is an issue with the hardware or the USB port. I have also tried both USB3 ports, on both RPi's and they perform the same

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry PI is your limiting factor.  The internal buss bottlenecks the USB.  Pi's are great for many purposes, but not for high throughput networking,